# Does Eclipse always run Proguard on Android release builds even if project.properties doesn't have a proguard entry?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

My app runs differently when run from Eclipse in debug mode, or when run from an exported signed application. I have not been specifying any proguard config in project.properties. Am I still getting some default proguard optimizations and obfuscations? Does proguard always run when exporting a signed binary using the generic config in the tools directory of the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You have to enable it. It's not enabled by  default. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

> To enable ProGuard so that it runs as part of an Ant or Eclipse build,
>   set the proguard.config property in the
>   /project.properties file. The path can be an absolute
>   path or a path relative to the project's root.

Comment: If its not ProGuard, I'm currently at a loss to explain the difference in operation. Any ideas on what else might differ between debug and signed release builds via Eclipse?

Comment: As far as I know, in debug mode, it picks up the debug keystore and signs it for you. In release mode, if you are using ant, it will ask for your private keystore. You can read more about here related to BuildConfig here. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html